# Spring 3 to 4 migration problems

Tags: java, spring

I have tests that extends `AbstractTransactionalSpringContextTests`, which is now deprecated. I am using `setComplete`, `endTransaction` and `startNewTransaction`.

What is the replacement use for these?

Comment: And also the extension aswell.

Answer (score 0):

For simple usage cases, you can use `@Transactional` and `@Commit`. If a test method is annotated with `@Transactional`, the test method will be performed inside a transaction, and a roll back will be performed after the test run. `@Commit` prevents this roll-back to be performed (similar to `setComplete`). You can use `@Transactional` on a test class for executing every test method in a transaction.

If you need more fine-grained control, take a look at the `AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContexTest` in combination with the static methods in `TestTransaction`. The [Spring Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.12.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#testcontext-tx-programmatic-tx-mgt) has a nice example of how to use `TestTransaction` for starting and ending transaction, or flagging them for a commit. When using `AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContexTest`, you need to keep in mind that it is already annotated with `@Transactional` on the class level.